# Ansible how to compare output of multiple hosts within the same task

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that has a task to output the list of installed Jenkins plugins for each servers.

here is the host file:

```
[masters]
server1
server2
server3
server4
server5
server6
```

Here is the task that prints out the list of plugins installed on each of the jenkins servers:

```
- name: Obtaining a list of Jenkins Plugins
  jenkins_script:
    script: 'println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)'
    url: "http://{{ inventory_hostname }}.usa.com:8080/"
    user: 'admin'
    password: 'password'
```

What I want to do next is do a comparison with all of the installed plugins across all of the servers -- to ensure that all of the servers are running the same plugins.

I don't necessarily want to force an update -- could break things -- just inform the user that they are running a different version of the plug in that the rest of the servers.

I am fairly new to ansible, will gladly accept any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit ugly, but should work:

```
- hosts: master
  tasks:
    - jenkins_script:
        script: 'println(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)'
        url: "http://{{ inventory_hostname }}.usa.com:8080/"
        user: 'admin'
        password: 'password'
      register: call_result

    - copy:
        content: '{{ call_result.output }}'
        dest: '/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}'
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

    - shell: 'diff /tmp/{{groups.master[0]}} /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}'
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      register: diff_result
      failed_when: false

    - debug:
        var: diff_result.stdout_lines
      when: diff_result.stdout_lines | length != 0
```

This will save the result of the `jenkins_script` module onto the calling host (where you are running `ansible-playbook`), into `/tmp/{{hostname}}`. Afterwards it will run a normal `diff` against the first server's result and each of the others', and then print out if there are any differences.

It's a bit ugly, as it:

- Uses `/tmp` on the calling host to store some temporary data
- Does not clean up after itself
- Uses the diff shell commands for something that might be doable with some clever use of jinja

Ansible 2.3 will have the [tempfile module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/tempfile_module.html), that you might use to clean up `/tmp`